# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'Product'

Tags: python, oop

**Here my code :**

```
def compute():
    choice = input("Average (A) or Total (T) Stock Level: ")
    stock_inventory.computeStockLevel(choice)

def computeStockLevel(self, choice):
        stockLevel = 0
        numberOfProducts = 0
        if choice == "T":
            for stocks in self.__product_list[-1]:
                stockLevel += stocks
            return stockLevel
        if choice == "A":
            for stocks in self.__product_list[-1]:
                stockLevel += stocks
                numberOfProducts += 1
                average = stockLevel / numberOfProducts
            return average

def __init__(self, uni_no, name, description, price, stock_level):
    self.__uni_no = uni_no
    self.__name = name
    self.__description = description
    self.__price = price
    self.__stock_level = stock_level

def add():
    uni_no = input("Key in Product Number: ")
    name = input("Key in Name of Product: ")
    description = input("Key in Product Description: ")
    price = input("Key in Product Price: ")
    stock_level = int(input("Key in Stock Level: "))
    stock_product = Product(uni_no, name, description, price, stock_level)
    stock_inventory.add_product(stock_product)
    print("Item has been successfully added")

def __init__(self):
    self.__product_list = []
def add_product(self, product):
    self.__product_list.append(product)
```

Trying to loop through product list to accumulate total & average stock level. However, received an error as shown in title.
Three functions are from three different files
Used OOP in the last set of codes (included get and set)
This is my first time using StackOverflow, please pardon me for the messy layout!

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you include a sample of what is in self._product_list? It seems to me that you are trying to add two different data types that are not compatible as exemplified in your error code. Ensure that stocks are integers and you should be fine.

Comment: @JasonChia Thanks for your reply! I have already edited the codes above by adding in what you mentioned.

Comment: Can you explain which library Product(kwargs) is from? As I mentioned earlier, you need to get the desired integer out to add it. I do not know what API that is so I can't be sure what is the correct way to get the integer which I would assume stock_level is meant to be.

Comment: @JasonChia I solved the problem already! Thanks for helping!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is here:

```
stockLevel += stocks
```

`stocks` comes from iterating through `self.__product_list[-1]`. Although it's not given here, I am guessing that this is a collection of `Product` objects, in which case you've tried to add a `Product` object to an `int`, resulting in the error you're getting.

Maybe you want

```
stockLevel += 1
```

?